# Числительное

Tags: числительные

50 149 тыс. руб. / 50 149 руб. и 250,0 тыс. руб./ 250 тыс. руб. - как правильно? Где можно посмотреть правило?

Answer (score 1):

Какое правило? Даже не припомню,чтобы об этом отдельно пояснялось. 50149 - читается как пятьдесят тысяч сто сорок девять. Зачем еще раз писать тысяч? Кстати, в  каких-то таблицах я встречала такой вариант, но это имеется в виду уже 50 миллионов 149 тысяч. Запятая в написании 250,0 - это математическая запись. А Вы вообще где это собираетесь писать? Если просто в предложении, то запятая и ноль, на мой взгляд, излишни. Если в бухгалтерском тексте или таблице, где у Вас в соседних графах, например, 250,3 - то,наверное,надо. Должно быть единообразное оформление.

Answer (score 0):

Если писать слово "тысяч" в первом примере, то оно должно стоять после числа 50:
50 тыс. 149 рублей. 
Только зачем? Может, так легче воспринимать, чем сплошную строку цифр? Впрочем, для этого можно использовать пробел: 50 149 руб. Иногда для этой же цели используют точку (в нашей системе записи) 50.149 или запятую 50,149 (в западной).  Но, вс илу того, что обе системы могут использоваться в наше время практически одновременно, это может привести к ошибкам.